# OnCellLeave strange bug in .NET

Tags: .net

Can anybody advise how to debug this bug in .NET 2.0?

I don't have any implementations of CellLeave in my C# project.

Some users of the program report this error on random basis, others never encounter it.

Thanks!

```
Report: Unhandled GUI exception occured!
Operating System: Microsoft Windows NT 5.1.2600.196608 Service Pack 3
System Type: 32 bit
Error Message: Index is less than 0 or more than or equal to the list count.
Parameter name: index
-1
  at System.Collections.ArrayList.ThrowNewArgumentOutOfRangeException (System.String name, System.Object actual, System.String message) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item (Int32 index) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellCollection.GetCellInternal (Int32 colIndex) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellCollection:GetCellInternal (int)
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.GetCellInternal (Int32 colIndex, Int32 rowIndex) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellLeave (System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.SetCurrentCellAddressCore (Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean setAnchorCellAddress, Boolean validateCurrentCell, Boolean throughMouseClick) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.MoveCurrentCell (Int32 x, Int32 y, Boolean select, Boolean isControl, Boolean isShift, Boolean scroll) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnRowsPreRemovedInternal (System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView:OnRowsPreRemovedInternal (System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs)
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.Clear () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnCollection.Clear () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.Dispose (Boolean disposing) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.ComponentModel.Component:Dispose ()
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose (Boolean disposing) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.ComponentModel.Component:Dispose ()
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose (Boolean disposing) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.ComponentModel.Component:Dispose ()
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose (Boolean disposing) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.Dispose (Boolean disposing) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.ComponentModel.Component:Dispose ()
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose (Boolean disposing) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.ComponentModel.Component:Dispose ()
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose (Boolean disposing) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.Dispose (Boolean disposing) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.Dispose (Boolean disposing) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at a.Dispose (Boolean  ) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.ComponentModel.Component:Dispose ()
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmClose (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlWindowTarget.OnMessage (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WndProc (IntPtr hWnd, Msg msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: The DataGridView control's internal state is corrupted.  The kind of bug that can be triggered when you update bound data from a worker thread.  But that's just a guess without knowing *anything* about your code.

Comment: Yes, that sounds possible, I use multithreading. I always try to Invoke the GUI thread from a worker thread when I need to update the contents of DGV, but perhaps I am missing somewhere. Does 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.Dispose' indicate that the error appears when the application is closing? (I do not create nor dispose of visual components at run time - they all get normally initialized at start up and disposed on exit).